# Avoid duplication in password protect URL with proxy in nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, basic-authentication

I have a Flask application served using `gunicorn`, and with NGINX on top of it. I want to use Basic Authentication (user/password) to protect all URL's starting with `/admin`, which is the back office, but still continue serving all other URLs with `gunicorn` without password.

Here is my current NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /admin {
        auth_basic "Administrator Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/app/.htpasswd;
        # the following four directives are duplicated :(
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

If I don't duplicate the `proxy_*` directives in the second location block, then the URLs starting with `/admin` doesn't get forwarded to `gunicorn` and I get a 404.

Is there any way to avoid the configuration duplication? I tried location nesting but apparently in the end NGINX only "executes" a single location block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy_pass must be within the location block.  However, there's no need to duplicate the proxy_set_header directives, they can be moved into the server block.  So your mistake was simply the assumption that proxy_pass could live in the server block :-)

Comment: That means the only directive I would need to repeat in both location blocks is `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;`, right? Moving the `proxy_set_header` ones to the server block.